# Как получить аватар и Имя по mail адресу gmail?

Tags: api, gmail

Нужно получить эти данные стороннего пользователя, указав его Gmail (не авторизуя его в oauth p/s без участия самого пользователя).

Нашел такой сервис: http://www.avatarapi.com/ но нет желания платить за информацию которая лежит где-то в паблике.

Перерыл Google API нашел только как получать из userId эти данные https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get а вот как получить userId из почты не нашел. Что подскажите?

У того сервиса в разделе "Как это работает" указано что информация берется публичная из Гугла.

Comment: Может быть сервис как-то парсит google plus?

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев Да берет оттуда, но не все.

Выявил такие действия, если на почте не создан google plus то сервис возвращает только userId. Это подтверждает что данные берутся оттуда.
А вот откуда берется userId, предположительно из какого то проекта, какого еще не нашел. Почему? Потому что когда я создаю новую почту на gmail то сервис про нее возвращает данные как "No profile information found for this email". Это говорит о том что сервис куда то обращается где еще новый аккаунт не засветился и не создал данные. Пробовал ютуб, создать канал. результаты нулевые. Буду дальше капать.

Comment: Все таки информация на сервисе появляется где-то через 10-20 минут, после того как я создам страницу в Google Plus, а когда ФИО меняю в GooglePlus то на сервисе сразу же выдает новые данные. Тем самым это предположительно они парсят в API google plus как то т.к. пока прокешируется в самом гугле информация о том что я создал страницу на это и уходит 10-20 мин. А вот старые аккаунты, на которых не создана страница, то нечего не выдают, то только userId на сервисе. Пойду капать google plus может найду нычку.

Answer (score 4):

Весь день рыскал по API Гугла, уже думал ладно надо набрать проксей да сделать скрипт для чека с того сайта, ибо там с 1 ипа 100 запросов можно.

И только сейчас на последней попытки начал гуглить именно на этот сервис, 3 ссылка с гугла выкинула на аналог еще из 2014 года https://github.com/eudoxia0/avatar-api/blob/master/src/avatar-api.lisp. Обращение идет на API какого-то picasaweb (в подробности не вдавался). Главное без какой либо авторизации вписываем нужный email адрес и получаем такие данные как Имя, UserId и ссылка на аватар: http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/vvputin@gmail.com?alt=json

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "encoding":"UTF-8",
    "entry":{
        "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$gphoto":"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007",
        "id":{"$t":"http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/111689979090137919444?alt=json"},
        "published":{"$t":"2016-09-09T17:20:24.602Z"},
        "updated":{"$t":"2016-09-08T12:05:14.519Z"},
        "category":[
            {
                "scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                "term":"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#user"
            }
        ],
        "title":{
            "$t":"111689979090137919444",
            "type":"text"
        },
        "summary":{
            "$t":"",
            "type":"text"
        },
        "link":[
            {
                "rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
                "type":"application/atom+xml",
                "href":"http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/111689979090137919444?alt=json"
            },
            {
                "rel":"alternate",
                "type":"text/html",
                "href":"https://picasaweb.google.com/111689979090137919444"
            },
            {
                "rel":"self",
                "type":"application/atom+xml",
                "href":"http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/111689979090137919444?alt=json"
            }
        ],
        "author":[
            {
                "name":{"$t":"vanyo1980"},
                "uri":{"$t":"https://picasaweb.google.com/111689979090137919444"}
            }
        ],
        "gphoto$user":{"$t":"111689979090137919444"},
        "gphoto$nickname":{"$t":"vanyo1980"},
        "gphoto$thumbnail":{
            "$t":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-t-Hdv_PGH4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/vrOJgVgMD6A/s64-c/111689979090137919444.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: тоже самое на php или js как можно сделать?